# Playing a video loop for multiple file types

Tags: javascript, arrays, video

I have an array of videos that I am playing as a loop on a website.  I've got that part working, but now I'm trying to figure out how to load the appropriate file formats.  I have the videos in both webm and mp4 formats.  I tried putting both file types in the array thinking that if it wasn't appropriate for the user's browser it just wouldn't load and skip to the next one (like video1.webm and video1.mp4 each had their own entry and there were 6 items in my array) but when I tested it in chrome it seemed to play each video twice.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<video autoplay id="myVideo">
<source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<script>
var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0] = 'video1.webm';
videoSource[1] = 'video2.webm';
videoSource[2] = 'video3.webm';
var i = 0;
var videoCount = 4;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); 

function myHandler() {
i++;
if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
    i = 0;
    videoPlay(i);
} else {
    videoPlay(i);
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <video autoplay id="myVideo">
<source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<script>
var videoSource = ['video1.webm', 'video2.webm', 'video3.webm', 'video4.webm'];

var i = 0;
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); 

function myHandler() {
if(i < videoCount){
    i++;
    videoPlay(i);
}else{
    i = 0;
    videoPlay(i);
}
}
</script>
```